# Connection to a db from localhost to another server with php

Tags: php

It's possible to create a mysql connection from localhost to another server using php, if it's possible, how? Thanks!

Comment: Change the connection settings, user/password/server. EX: $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=the_server_address;dbname=test', $user, $pass);

Comment: possible duplicate of [Connecting to remote MySQL server using PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1935314/connecting-to-remote-mysql-server-using-php)

Comment: One important thing is that your remote server should allow remote connections. http://stackoverflow.com/a/14779244/1501051

Comment: it is simple, i just want to create a connection from my localhost pc to my domaint http://www.something.something, to read the mysql db from domain, and administation from localhost, to don't connect to my server and disconect, and to this forever

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible.You must have the username and password of that domain in which you want to connect.

```
mysqli_connect("www.domain.com","username","password","database_name")or die("Error " . mysqli_error());
```

Comment: please mark it useful if it works for you

Comment: @UnicoRahul username password is needed for the database not for domain (host)

Comment: @عثمان غني The question is about mysql connection and mysql connection means he wants to connect with database

Comment: "You must have the username and password of that domain..." so I am saying

Comment: عثمان غني that is obvious

Answer (score 1):

```
$host_name = "www.yourdomain.com";
$database = "pdo"; // Change your database name
$username = "root"; // Your database user id
$password = "test"; // Your password
try {
    $dbo = new PDO('mysql:host='.$host_name.';dbname='.$database,  $username, $password);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    print "Error!: " . $e->getMessage() . "<br/>";
    die();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Simply pass following details about your server:

```
<?php
$servername = "your-server-name-or-ip";
$username = "your-server-username";
$password = "your-server-password";

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$url = 'mysql:host=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx;dbname=xxxxxx'
$username = xxx;
$password = xxx;

$db = new PDO($url, $username, $password);

$query = $db->query('select * from some_table');
$query->execute();
$res = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```