# Remote connection mysql in php using virtual machine

Tags: apache, ubuntu, virtual-machine

[Question I was refering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1935314/connecting-to-remote-mysql-server-using-php/11377719#11377719)

I create three virtual Machine running Ubuntu 14.04 in VMWare Player.
First VM - Client who will access the web pages.
Second VM - Apache Web Server and PHP Server
Third VM - MYSQL Database Server.

I was able to create user in third vm , providing it all the privileges .
Using two commands
Create User using this command.

```html
mysql> CREATE USER 'user'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '123456';
mysql> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON project_2.* TO 'user'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Checking it is working

```html
mysql -u root -h your.mysql.server.address –p
```

I have reach to this step without any error and is able to access database and perform operations on it.

Now i am looking to write a php  script to access the database in web browser
but unable to do it.
Php script is kept in Second VM.

My code For php script is

```html
<?php
$conn = mysql_connect('database','user','123456');
if(!$conn){
echo "bye";
}
else{
echo "hi";
}
mysql_select_db('project_2',$conn);
$query="select * from test";
$result=mysql_query($query);

echo "<table border='1'>";
echo "<tr>";
echo "<th>Name</th>";
echo "</tr>";

while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
echo "<tr>";
echo "<td>",$row['name'],"</td>";
echo "</tr>";
}


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

> sudo apt-get install php5-mysql

this may solve your problem