# how to connect database in different server?

Tags: php, mysql

I am using two domain name ('domain1','domain2') and 2 server('server A' and 'server B'). 'domain1' is the Main domain. 'domain2', i am using as backend like, to store data. So the data will be stored in server B. When i use 'domain1' in browser it will display the data which is stored in 'server B' . I am not using 'server A' .

I have done some code. Please go through it and let me know what correction i have to do. The code is below,

```
//these hostname,dbname,user and password from server B,(is this correct?)
$hostname   =   "1.1.1.1"   ;
$database   =   "db_B"      ;
$user       =   "u_B"       ;
$pasword    =   "u_pas"     ;
$conn   = mysqli_connect($hostname,$user,$pasword,$database) ;
if (!$conn)
{
    die ("Error connecting to the database because : " . 
    mysqli_error($conn))    ;
}
```

Comment: try with server B's ip and default port 3306

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Connecting to remote MySQL server using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1935314/connecting-to-remote-mysql-server-using-php)

Comment: Learn about Rest API... it s the secure way of two server connection..

Comment: I think, connection is happening. Problem is, you are using the wrong variable `$dbconn`. Your connection variable is `$conn`.

Comment: Are you asking for code review or? Is there something wrong, some error or?

Comment: see i have two domain (domain1, domain 2) and two server(server A, server B). The data in Server B should come and display on the screen , when i type the url -  domain1.com. So, i need to connect server B.

Comment: So, what's happen when you load the site A?

Comment: error is comng 'Access denied for user.....'. Its not connecting to the database in server B.

Comment: `Server B` is blocking you`(e.g. Server A)`. Check the firewall + if this user with which you're connecting is having permissions to do that.

Comment: what i have done that, i added the server B's  'host:1.1.1.1' in server A (in Remote MySQL) .

Comment: You need to add server A to server B. Did you check the linked thread?

Comment: Yes i added in Remote MySQL

Comment: What did you added? Did you grant the user with permissions?

Comment: That permission thing i din't  do. .. Can you please help me todo this. Can you tell me in step by step.

Comment: Everything you need is in linked thread. Please check it

Comment: ok. Thank you..I will check it

Answer (score 0):

```
In domain1 config.php file i have written the following code. It's working for me.

$servername   =   "domain2.in"   ;
$database     =   "db_B"         ;//server B's database name
$user         =   "u_B"          ;//server B's database's(db_B) user name
$pasword      =   "u_pas"        ;//server B's database's(db_B) password

$conn   = mysqli_connect($servername,$user,$pasword,$database) ;
if (!$conn)
{
    die ("Error connecting to the database because : " . 
    mysqli_error($conn))    ;
}

after this, add "server A"'s Remote MySQL hostname in "server B"'s Remote MySQL.
```